# How can I retrieve data with queryEqualToValue in auto id child. Firebase-iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As my question. I can't retrieve data from firebase when I try to use "queryEqualToValue" with auto id key.

```
self.ref.child(..my child..).queryOrderByChild("name").queryEqualToValue("my name")
```

auto child id above child "name".

Edit: for my json tree

- Students

  - (auto id)

    - name

      - first name
      - nick name

My real data doesn't like this but this's for example structure.
I really want to check equal to "first name".

Here's my code

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
ref.child("Students").queryOrderedByChild("name").queryEqualToValue("Jason bourne").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in 
   print("value : " + snapshot.value)
}
```

Comment: You mean childByAutoId()? Why would you use that when reading from database?
I am sorting and using queryEqualToValue too. Here is an example:
ref.child("posts").queryOrderByChild("creator").queryEqualToValue("Mike")... After child("posts") there should be chid(postKey) but you ignore that when using queryOrderByChild()

Comment: Give your JSON tree as text not snippet

Comment: @Dravidian I edited for JSON tree. thanks guy

Comment: @ZassX I know your point but I edited for example my data structure. that can't retrieve data with your code.

Comment: You need to change `queryOrderedByChild("name")` to `queryOrderedByChild("name/first name")` and `observeEventType(.Value` to `observeEventType(.ChildAdded`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your realtime database looks something like this:

```
{
    "students": {
        1: {
            "name": {
                "first_name": "Nathapong",
                "nick_name": "Oniikal3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can observe the students path with the event type `ChildAdded` and order the query by child key `name/first_name`. Then you can use `queryEqualToValue` to find students with a particular first name.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath('students').queryOrderByChild("name/first_name").queryEqualToValue("Nathapong")

ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, block: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work. Check for names if I made any mistakes and insert your data.

```
self.ref.child("Students").child("name").queryOrderedByChild("first name").queryEqualToValue("my name").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    print(snapshot.value)
}
```

Comment: I have tried with this solution but It's not work. It's still return null.

Comment: @Oniikal3 can you paste some more code so we can see?

Comment: @ZassX I try to remove queryEqualToValue(). It should return all value in Students right?. but It doesn't.

Comment: @Oniikal3 no.
This should return all students:
self.ref.child("Students").observeSingleEventOfType ...

Comment: @ZassX I just updated my code. My requirement is I need to retrieve student data that's match with my name ("Jason bourne").

Comment: @Oniikal3 Well everything is ok. There must be a problem with your entries. Can you copy some examples from firebase?

Comment: I fixed my issue with @Callam answer. many thanks for you too.

Comment: (.Value) has been renamed to (.value)

Answer (score 0):

Before use queries with child, you need to specify this using `".indexOn":["name"]` in Database Rules. See [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) for examples

```
{
    "rules":{
        ".write": "true",
        ".read": "true",
        "Students": {
            "$key": {
                ".indexOn":["name"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your read/write rules can go where you need it. `.indexOn` is just like another rule, alongside with `.validate`

Comment: Thanks Dima, I edited for my data structure. please can you see it.

Comment: This is proper way yes, but should also work without this.

Comment: @ZassX it will throw an exception without it, on iOS at least. If you have another solution - please, share it

Comment: @DimaRostopira it throws warning but still returns results. But sure, you have to add this. Was just pointing out that it can be tested any way.

Comment: @DimaRostopira I think this's just an order results?. or I'm misunderstand.